# How to properly use qmake's "system" command output

Tags: qt, build, qt4, qmake

Such `qmake` project (*.pro) code successfully work under Ubuntu Linux, but under Windows 8 it don't:

```
win32 {
    BUILD_TIME = $$system ("time /T")
}
else
{
    BUILD_TIME = $$system ("time")
}
message($$BUILD_TIME) # output the current time
```

The output is "time /T", i.e. command itself instead of command execution value.
Is this behaviour a bug, or just i'm doing smth wrong? :)

UPD: i've found the another way to obtain current date: `$$_DATE_`. However,
i don't like to use undocumented feature - it is bad idea.

P.S. My target is just to generate unique build ID string. I'm using Qt 4.8.5.

Comment: Any nontrivial real-world use of `qmake` unfortunately has to rely on a whole bunch of undocumented features. Don't worry, they won't be taken away from you. `qmake` is in pure maintenance mode, it is meant to stay stable "forever". Use `qbs` if you can, it's going to be the future.

Comment: @KubaOber Hm, i have already found the `_DATE_` env variable in qmake, that can solve my problem alternatively - and it is undocumented. As the influence of the one damn space to the qmake parser work ;(
And - can you give the example of the large project with `qbs` usage?

Comment: I use qbs to build Qt itself. I don't know if that counts as big enough :)

Comment: @KubaOber Yes, it is :) But as i understood `qbs` is not ready yet for production usage - e.g. Qt Creator don't allow to create qbs-based Qt project, only non-Qt one oO

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following commands work fine for me:

```
win32 {
    BUILD_TIME = $$system("time /T") # no spaces between 'system' command and args.
} else {
    BUILD_TIME = $$system("time")
}
message($$BUILD_TIME) # output the current time
```

Note, that I removed space between `$$system` and `("time /T")`